# default_scope and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, default-scope

Suppose I have a Post model, and a Comment model. Using a common pattern, Post has_many Comments.

If Comment has a default_scope set:

```
default_scope where("deleted_at IS NULL")
```

How do I easily retrieve ALL comments on a post, regardless of scope?
This produces invalid results:

```
Post.first.comments.unscoped
```

Which generates the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM comments;
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = 1;
```

Running:

```
Post.first.comments
```

Produces:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND post_id = 1;
```

I understand the basic principle of unscoped removing all existing scopes, but shouldn't it be aware and to keep the association scope?

What is the best way to pull ALL comments?

Comment: Why don't you think around it and create  a `scope :active, where("deleted_at IS NULL")` and called it when required?

Comment: That's what I would do as well. If you find yourself having to "undo" your default, then it's not really a good default.

Comment: I do not agree on that. I think it is good practice to hide by default and explicitly override that default when needed. This is somehow related to Rails' XSS counter-measures. You had to html_escape every user generated content output in Rails 2. Nowadays, everything is escaped by default and you have to override it manually even if you have much non-user-generated content. It is about security. Information safety in this case. You could get sued for having an unlawful comment on your page because you forgot the named_scope. Or clients freak out to see unpublished content on some page.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335726/eager-loading-of-deleted-records-with-paranoias-default-scope

Answer (score 17):

For some strange reasons,

```
Comment.unscoped { Post.last.comments }
```

includes the `default_scope` of `Comment`,

however,

```
Comment.unscoped { Post.last.comments.to_a }
Comment.unscoped { Post.last.comments.order }
```

do **not** include the `default_scope` of `Comment`.

I experienced this in a `rails console` session with `Rails 3.2.3`.

Comment: I'm experiencing your issue, in my case `Post.last.comments.order` works, while `Post.last.comments.to_a` is broken. Have you found any clue on this? I'll try to upgrade my app to the latest Rails to see if this is fixed.

Comment: This happens also in 3.2.6, probably a bug.

Comment: Still exists in `rails 4.1.1`, `order(:id)` helps to exclude the default_order.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5591) for more info on the problem.

Answer (score 10):

`with_exlusive_scope` is deprecated as of Rails 3. See [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bd1666ad1de88598ed6f04ceffb8488a77be4385).

Before (Rails 2):

```
Comment.with_exclusive_scope { Post.find(post_id).comments }
```

After (Rails 3):

```
Comment.unscoped { Post.find(post_id).comments }
```

Answer (score 8):

`Rails 4.1.1`

```
Comment.unscope(where: :deleted_at) { Post.first.comments }
```

Or

```
Comment.unscoped { Post.first.comments.scope }
```

**Note** that I added `.scope`, it seems like this block should return kind of `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` (what `.scope` does) not `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`  (without a `.scope`)

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed a very frustrating problem which violates the principle of least surprise.

For now, you can just write:

```
Comment.unscoped.where(post_id: Post.first)
```

This is the most elegant/simple solution IMO.

Or:

```
Post.first.comments.scoped.tap { |rel| rel.default_scoped = false }
```

The advantage of the latter:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.with_deleted
    scoped.tap { |rel| rel.default_scoped = false }
  end
end
```

Then you can make fun things:

```
Post.first.comments.with_deleted.order('created_at DESC')
```

Since Rails 4, Model.all returns an ActiveRecord::Relation , rather than an array of records.
So you can (and should) use `all` instead of `scoped`:

```
Post.first.comments.all.tap { |rel| rel.default_scoped = false }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
# Use this scope by default
scope :active, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }

# Use this whenever you want to include all comments regardless of their `deleted_at` value
scope :with_soft_deleted, -> { unscope(where: :deleted_at)

default_scope, -> { active }
```

`post.comments` would fire this query:

```
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "comments"."post_id" = $1;
```

`post.comments.with_soft_deleted` would send this:

```
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Comment
  def post_comments(post_id)
    with_exclusive_scope { find(all, :conditions => {:post_id => post_id}) }
  end
end

Comment.post_comments(Post.first.id)
```

Comment: To me that feels a bit hackish though. Posts/Comments, is only an example, you wouldn't want to repeat this across many different models would you?

I realize I didn't mention that originally too.

Comment: This will get really ugly really quickly. If this too hackish to your taste (it really is hackish), try to re-evaluate using default_scope in the first place.

Comment: Wow! this is preatty broken in rails! Like this, the default_scope is unusable. There should be post.unscoped_comments and  comment.unscoped_post methods generated...

Comment: I agree. That would be nice to have post.unscoped_comments. But at least you can always do Comment.unscoped { post.comments } to disable the default scope temporarily (for everything inside of the unscoped{} block)...