# How to unscope an associated record in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having some trouble getting scoping to work correctly in rails.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => 'users.deleted_at IS NULL'


class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :author_id
```

When I call the following:

```
feeds = Feed.includes(:user)
```

I want to skip over the default_scope for users. so I tried:

```
feeds = Feed.unscoped.includes(:user)
```

But this is not removing the scope from users. Any suggestions on how I can get this to work? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963124/default-scope-and-associations or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758145/how-to-use-unscoped-on-associated-relations-in-rails3 help?

Comment: Sadly, no. The first one is outdated. The 2nd one isn't detailing using includes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `.unscoped` in block form, as documented [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped):

```
User.unscoped do
  @feeds = Feed.includes(:user).all
end
```

Note that whether or not the default scope applies depends on whether or not you're inside the block *when the query is actually executed*. That's why the above uses `.all`, forcing the query to execute.

Thus, while the above works, this won't - the query is executed outside the `.unscoped` block and the default scope will apply:

```
User.unscoped do
  @feeds = Feed.includes(:user)
end
@feeds #included Users will have default scope
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following, giving how I am querying for Feeds,and including :user for performance. How would this apply?

Comment: @AnApprentice You asked how to avoid using the default scope on an association listed in `.includes`. This is how. You still eager load Users, but don't limit it to ones that aren't deleted. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks, Yes but perhaps I'm not understanding the end to end to get this to work. Can you maybe share what I need to update and how to use it?

Comment: Basically, you replace the `feeds = Feed.includes(:user)` with the block I provided wherever you use it, and it should solve the problem. (tested with Rails 3.2.2). Is that not happening?

Comment: ok I needed to set it to @feeds so it was available outside. While it didn't error, it still is applying the scope to users: User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1216, 1) AND (users.deleted_at IS NULL)

Comment: A thought - the use or non-use of the default scope appears to depend on the point at which the relation actually gets executed and converted into an array. If you make sure that happens inside the block, it leaves off the default scope. If it doesn't, it doesn't. (going to edit answer to reflect this).